# dispatchTouchEvent() is crashing on Vivo device, Android 12 with 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()'

Tags: java, android, crashlytics, android-videoview, android-touch-event

Firebase Crashlytics is reporting the following log specifically on Vivo devices, Android 12 OS. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:626)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14961)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6799)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6565)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6022)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6089)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6050)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6058)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6280)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6026)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6089)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6050)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6058)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6026)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9119)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:9070)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9016)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9254)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:276)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:186)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8348)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1065)
```

Comment: It looks like a NPE in the code of the Android system - Vivo's bug.

Comment: I'm facing this too